# Multiple word search in one field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have search functionality with this code in the 'search.rb' file:

```
votsphonebooks = votsphonebooks.where("address like ?", "%#{address}%") if address.present?
```

There are multiple fields, this is just one of them.

How can I successfully change this line into something like a map to include multiple words.

Eg. If they type in '123 Fake St' - it will look for exactly that, but I want it to search for '123', 'Fake', 'St'.

Comment: `votsphonebooks.where("address like ?", "%#{address}%").map(:f1,:f2)`
try this f1,f2 is your field name

Comment: I only have one field for the search, but it appears like this on my searches/new.html.erb:

    <%= f.label :address%>
    <%= f.text_field :address, class: "form-control"  %>

Comment: `votsphonebooks.where("address like ?", "%#{address}%").map(&:address)`

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is split the `address` by spaces:

```
addresses = params[:address].split(" ")
```

Then what you need is a `OR` query, you could do it by using [ARel](https://github.com/rails/arel).

```
t = VotsPhoneBook.arel_table # The class name is my guess
arel_query = addresses.reduce(nil) do |q, address|
  q.nil? ? t[:address].matches("%#{address}%") : q.or(t[:address].matches("%#{address}%"))
end

results = Post.where(arel_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`:

```
address_arr = address.split(" ")

votsphonebooks = votsphonebooks.where('address REGEXP ?',address_arr.join('|')) unless address_arr.blank?
```

Comment: Tried this one, does it make a difference that I'm using TDS to connect to a MS SQL Server Database? The error I got was:
    TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near 'REGEXP'